# App-level gradle for unity project on Android platform

Tags: android, firebase, unity-game-engine, gradle

I am using Firebase Database with unity 5.6.1. I am building an android app with the (new) gradle method because I have way too many field references than allowed. The Firebase instructions say the following:

```
1.Project-level build.gradle (<project>/build.gradle):

buildscript {
   dependencies {
      // Add this line
      classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.0'
   }
}

2.App-level build.gradle (<project>/<app-module>/build.gradle):

dependencies {
    // Add this line
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:12.0.0'
}
...
// Add to the bottom of the file
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Here is my **AndroidManifest.xml** file:

```
    -<manifest android:versionName="1.0" android:versionCode="1" android:installLocation="preferExternal" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" package="com.unity3d.player" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:smallScreens="true"/>


    -<application android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication" android:debuggable="true" android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@drawable/app_icon" android:theme="@style/UnityThemeSelector">


    -<activity android:name="com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity" android:label="@string/app_name">


    -<intent-filter>

    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>

    </intent-filter>

    <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.UnityActivity" android:value="true"/>

    </activity>

    <activity android:name="com.facebook.unity.FBUnityLoginActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mnc|mcc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode|touchscreen"/>

    <activity android:name="com.facebook.unity.FBUnityDialogsActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mnc|mcc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode|touchscreen"/>

    <activity android:name="com.facebook.unity.FBUnityAppLinkActivity" android:exported="true"/>

    <activity android:name="com.facebook.unity.FBUnityDeepLinkingActivity" android:exported="true"/>

    <activity android:name="com.facebook.unity.FBUnityGameRequestActivity"/>

    <activity android:name="com.facebook.unity.FBUnityCreateGameGroupActivity"/>

    <activity android:name="com.facebook.unity.FBUnityJoinGameGroupActivity"/>

    <activity android:name="com.facebook.unity.AppInviteDialogActivity"/>

    <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="fb142416569762965"/>

    <provider android:name="com.facebook.FacebookContentProvider" android:exported="true" android:authorities="com.facebook.app.FacebookContentProvider142416569762965"/>

    </application>

    </manifest>
```

Here, the project-level build.gradle means the mainTemplate.gradle file in **Assets/Plugins/Android/mainTemplate.gradle**. But where should I add the app-level grade file? I tried to make a folder called 'app' in **Assets/Plugins/Android** and write the instructed statements. But, it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: show you manifest file

Comment: have you used gradle(new) option

Comment: check this out https://stackoverflow.com/a/46799120/9287163

Comment: @krishankTripathi I have added the AndroidManifest.xml file.

Comment: go through the full setup walkthrough here https://support.unity3d.com/hc/en-us/articles/115005695763-Exporting-a-project-to-Gradle-and-building-deploying-on-Android-Studio

Comment: did you find the issues?

Comment: Does your `AndroidManifest.xml` really have those dashes in? That does not look like valid XML to me.